# Inside a react app, how can I dynamically create an element(div) and render a react app inside that?

Tags: javascript, forms, reactjs, iframe, react-redux

I am building a chat application using react-redux. This chat application will take multiple interactions at a time and  user can switch between them.

```
class Chat extends React.Component  {
 render() {
    return(
         //children components
    )

  }
}
ReactDom.render(<Chat/>,document.getElementById('app'))
```

I have a survey form component as a child component of the  app. 
survey form is loaded inside an iframe and the contents of the form are loaded from server which are different for different interactions. So whenever a new interaction comes to user I re-render survey form component the whole thing with the new form data ( list of iframes in this case one for each interaction) .

Now the problem is that it will render the initial form contents every time, let's say I have filled the first form and when a new interaction comes up (state change :rerender with the list) there will be 2 forms with initial content received from the server making me lose the data which I have filled.

Question : How can I retain this filled contents?

A probable solution would be storing the current form contents in a redux-store with the key as interaction and rendering it for the particular interaction, when the iframe unloads but I do not want to do that.

Is there anyway where I can dynamically (on new interaction ) create a new div or any element and render the surveyformcomponent (containing single iframe) again so that other components are not re-rendered. So that there will be new iframe rendered inside a div without affecting the previously rendered iframes.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Its a stretch but you probably do another ReactDOM render call inside the componentDidMount lifecycle method of your parent class. You could also us the lifecycle method `shouldComponentUpdate` to gain more control over the rerendering.

```
shouldCompnentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
  if (/*something changed and you need to rerender explicitly*/) {
     return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Stephen L!! If I have understood correctly,

Inside SurveyComponent class u render SurveyComponent again inside shouldCompnentUpdate by creating new id.
//looks ugly
`
shouldCompnentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
  if (/*something changed and you need to rerender explicitly*/) {
      document.createElement('div')// assign some unique id like app_1;
     ReactDom.render(<SurveyComponent>, newlyCreatedDivId)
  }
return false; //always return false
}`
I did not understand the use of ComponentDidMount for this case!!